# Parameterize the equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, parametric

Find a way of parameterizing the following curve: $y^2=\sin x $.

I have already tried $x(t) = (\sqrt t, \sin^{-1} t) $ but this only gives part of the curve because of the nature of the sqrt function and the sine function. Any suggestions?

Comment: The curve consists of unit circles centered on $(4k+1)\pi/2$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Since those circles are not connected, any parametrization must be discontinuous.

Comment: In fact, since there are infinitely many disconnected circles in the curve, any parametrization must have infinitely many discontinuities, which basically rules out a closed-form parametrization like you seem to be looking for.